# If I install the app in another device, is it still possible to log in with the pre-made ID?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

For my best knowledge so far, the biggest difference between SQLite and MySQL is that it does not require a server to run, as SQLite stores data in a database file in each device.

The question rising from this part is..

Let's say I created an Android app which simply contains login and signup features. By installing this app in one device I create an ID with a password (let's say the ID is ricoangeloni and the password is 1234).

If I install the app in another device, is it still possible to log in with the pre-made ID? This is still very confusing, as I am probably not sure if the clients are sharing the centre database.

Comment: Your intuition is correct; the database needs to be on the server for this to work properly.  It's probably not going to be SQLite, although SQLite would work in theory if the overall load weren't too high.

Comment: MySQL doesn't require a server to run either, I have a copy running on my home machine.  The website (which gets 2-3 unique hits per day) runs on the same machine.  The difference between the two is that they're totally different databases with different codebases and different feature sets.  But both are databases, and both use SQL.

Comment: Have you considered integrating with Google Play Services?  With that, you can take advantage of authenticating based on the signed in Google user account.  No worrying about infrastructure.  Also, this handles allowing the user to have many devices with the same account.

Comment: @GabeSechan That's not what server-less means. MySQL requires a server process, which clients connect to. SQLite doesn't; it runs in the process that's calling the MySQL functions, because it's an ordinary C library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on where the database is located (regardless of whether you're using SQLite or MySQL to access the database).  If you're storing the database on the Android device, then that database is specific to that device.

If the database however is stored on some internet-facing computer (doesn't have to be a "server" per say) and your app interacts with that hosted database, then an account created in that database is accessible from anywhere, not just your app.  A website for example could also use the accounts in that database for login purposes.

The approach of housing the database on the device does have its advantages, namely you don't need to have a dedicated machine to host the database.  But, if you wanted to have one database with all of the accounts and use that for authentication purposes, you're going to need to put that database on the internet.